# Not sure why posts aren't inserting into my database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have gone over everything I can think of but can't figure out why my code is creating an error message and not inserting into the database, I even put echo "
Select SQL = ".$sql2."
"; before my results query and got the following data...

```
Select SQL = INSERT INTO `posts`(post_topic, post_id, post_content, post_date, post_by)VALUES('3', '2', 'me too', '15/07/13 22:04:00', '1'
ERROR
```

Checking with the values, everything is right, the topic the post is joined to is 3, it's the 2nd post in the posts table, "me too" is the correct post content, data is fine, and the session user_id is 1, I am at a loss, here is the complete code for the page.

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 

// Get value of id that sent from hidden field 
$id=$_POST['id'];

// Find highest answer number. 
$sql="SELECT MAX(post_id) AS Maxa_id FROM `posts` WHERE post_topic='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

// add + 1 to highest answer number and keep it in variable name "$Max_id". if there no answer yet set it = 1 
if ($rows) {
$Max_id = $rows['Maxa_id']+1;
}
else {
$Max_id = 1;
}

// get values that sent from form 

$post_content=$_POST['post_content']; 

$datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s"); // create date and time

// Insert answer 
$sql2="INSERT INTO `posts`(post_topic, post_id, post_content, post_date, post_by)VALUES('$id', '$Max_id', '$post_content', '$datetime', '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
echo "<BR>Select SQL = ".$sql2."<BR>";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

if($result2){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href='view_topic.php?topic_id=".$id."'>View your answer</a>";

// If added new answer, add value +1 in reply column 

$sql3="UPDATE `topics` SET reply='$Max_id' WHERE topic_id='$id'";
echo "<BR>Select SQL = ".$sql3."<BR>";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// Close connection
mysql_close();
?>
<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Comment: when you type "INSERT INTO `posts`(post_topic, post_id, post_content, post_date, post_by)VALUES('$id', '$Max_id', '$post_content', '$datetime', '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'" into your phpmyadmin what error do you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"INSERT INTO posts(post_topic, post_id, post_content, post_date, post_by)VALUES(' at line 1

Comment: It looks like you included a double quote before the INSERT statement when you ran the query. To debug this, take the contents of the query that PHP would have run, and run that exact same statement in another environment. (Also, your datetime format is incorrect for a MySQL DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, date portion should be format YYYY-MM-DD, not dd/mm/yy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your VALUES statement you are missing ), you just have "; currently.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing parenthesis in the end of $sql2. Its alright, it happens to everyone.

Comment: Thanks, hasn't fixed my issue though :(